# Increase cell height according to child WebView iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiwebview, cell

I have a UIWebView inside a UITableViewCell, which loads an HTML string. I have made this UIWebview to take the complete height according to the data in it. Now I also want to increase the Cell height to the height of the webview.

I have tried something like so :-

```
 public override void LoadingFinished(UIWebView webView)
            {
                if (!webView.IsLoading)
                {

                    var contentSize = ContentWebView.ScrollView.ContentSize;
                    contentSize.Height = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
                    ContentWebView.ScrollView.ContentSize = contentSize;

                    CGRect newFrame = TableHeader.Frame;
                    newFrame.Height = newFrame.Size.Height + contentSize.Height;

                    CellContentView.Frame = newFrame;


                }
            }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you get correct contentSize value? Don't you reload tableView so cell's height remains same, is it? I guess you can have a reference to autolayout constraint height for webView and dinamically change it.

Comment: Do you know the content what you want to show in web view ?

Comment: I guess it's a bad idea to have a UIWebView inside UITableViewCell since it is reused and every time you have to load webView content again during scrolling

Comment: @BharathVankireddy I get the content to load in the webview froma service. It is a string.

Comment: @Injectios I basically want the whole view to be scrollable as i have 2 labels, 1 webview, 1 list, 1 textfield and a button on the same page. So I show the 2 labels in the table header, the webview in one cell, the list in another cell and the textfield and the button in the footer view. Can I achieve this behaviour of full scroll with the webview and the list showing all its content by any other approach?

Comment: yes, you can do it with a UIScrollView, I guess it's easier to have dynamic height for UIWebView in your case. Just create constraint "height" for UIWebView and after u loaded content - update this constraint

Comment: @Injectios So you suggest I should stick to the same approach Im using or should I switch to using a scrollview, because I had tried that earlier, but as I am using autolayouts, I could not make it work.

Comment: there are so many ways to achieve it, but if you prefer to use UITableView to keep your layout, what you can do is load webView once and keep reference on webView (OR cell), so after you reload cell webView keeps content (I can come up with obj-c example later if still needed)

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you have to return some default height. Once web view loaded, reload only that particular cell(using tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths method). Content height of the web view can calculated using code:

```
[[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollHeight;"] floatValue]
```

Call above code in webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method of the web view.

Your tableview delegate method will look some thing like:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if //while Web view is loading
    return //default Height
    else
    return //calculated Height in webViewDidFinishLoad method.
}
```

Comment: reload cell would reload webView content right? Will it not lead to cycle?

Comment: Iam able to make the Webview take full height but the cell size does not increase

Answer (score 0):

Once you have string which you render in web view, call following method to get the height required to render by that string using following method,

```
- (CGSize)getHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
if (text) {
    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
    size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+20.0f);
}
return size;
}
```

Update `heightForRowAtIndexpath` method as,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

return [self getHeightForText:[self.valuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] havingWidth:323.0f andFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0f]].height;
}
```

In above method, you may also check for web view content string availability by writing some if condition. If content is not yet available you return `44.0f` standard height for that cell.

Once content of web view is available , call following method of tableview by passing index path of the cell.

```
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[iPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```